# CSS / HTML layering problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have made a toggle-switch in HTML with a label and styled in css. When the toggle is on its working as intended, but when its off the label overlaps with the switch.

[image: Not working as planned]

[image: Working as planned]

The toggle container wont layer on top of the label element. I have tried with z-index and different positions, but to no avail.
Built with React, and the CSS is in the pre-made App.css file.

React // HTML // Javascript

```
const toggleClasses = classNames('wrg-toggle', {
  'wrg-toggle--checked': toggle,
  'wrg-toggle--disabled': disabled
}, className);
    return(
      <div
      onMouseOver={() => setHoveredElement(5)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredElement(null)}
    >
     <div onClick={triggerToggle} className={toggleClasses}>
            <div className="wrg-toggle-container">
            <label htmlFor="grid">Enable grid</label>
                <div className="wrg-toggle-check">
                    <span>{ getIcon('checked')}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="wrg-toggle-uncheck">
                    <span>{ getIcon('unchecked')}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wrg-toggle-circle"></div>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Toggle Button" className="wrg-toggle-input" />
        </div>
  </div>
    );
};
```

CSS code

```
.wrg-toggle {
  touch-action: pan-x;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5em;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.wrg-toggle-input {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.wrg-toggle-check, .wrg-toggle-uncheck {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}


.wrg-toggle-check {
  z-index: 3;
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  
}
.wrg-toggle-uncheck {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  position:inherit;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
  
}
label {
  float: right;
  right: 0.5em;
  width: 8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #8E9092;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 ; 
  height: 24px;
  border: solid 1px;
  top: -1.3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrg-toggle-uncheck span, 
.wrg-toggle-check span {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
}

.wrg-toggle-container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #f5f6f8;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  border: solid 1px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wrg-toggle-container .wrg-toggle-check{
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  left: -0.3px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color:#61dafb;
  border: solid 1px;
  top: 0px;
}

.wrg-toggle-circle{
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1) 0ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 30;
}
.wrg-toggle--checked .wrg-toggle-check{
  opacity: 1;
  position:relative;
  border-top: 2px;
  border-left: -3px;
}
.wrg-toggle--checked .wrg-toggle-uncheck {
  opacity: 0;
  border: 0;
  
}
.wrg-toggle--checked .wrg-toggle-circle {
  left: 27px;
} 
.wrg-toggle--checked .wrg-toggle-circle:after {
  content: "✔";
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

added a

```
.wrg-toggle-container .wrg-toggle-uncheck {
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
}
```